# Vim 8.1.0037 update breaks multiple plugins

Tags: vim, nerdtree, ctrlp, vim-fugitive, vim-airline

I have updated my vim to 8.1.0037 (`vim --version` showed compiled 13th June), and when I opened it today multiple plugins are broken.

on a restart and reinstall all these plugins, they are still broken.

Any direction? it seems to me that the update has broken the plugins.

my `.vimrc` looks like:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on 
set number
set encoding=utf-8

autocmd vimenter * NERDTree /home/myname
map <F4> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
```

error messages looks like below.

```
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim:
line   13:
E475: Invalid argument: 
line   14:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   15:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
Error detected while processing function ctrlp#mrufiles#opts:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: 
E15: Invalid expression: ['g:ctrlp_mruf_', {
line    2:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line    3:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line    4:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line    5:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line    6:
line   10:
E121: Undefined variable: opts
E116: Invalid arguments for function items(opts)
E15: Invalid expression: items(opts)
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim:
line   50:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   53:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim:
line   39:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   40:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
Error detected while processing function <SNR>45_setup_options:
line    6:
E697: Missing end of List ']': 
E15: Invalid expression: [
Error detected while processing 

/home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim:
    line   88:
    E15: Invalid expression: 
    E15: Invalid expression: has('multi_byte') && has('unix') && &encoding == 'utf-8' &&
    line   89:
    E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
    Error detected while processing function <SNR>45_setup_keymaps:
    line    1:
    E697: Missing end of List ']': 
    E15: Invalid expression: [
    Error detected while processing function airline#init#bootstrap:
    line   24:
    E15: Invalid expression: 
    E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
    line   25:
    E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
    line   26:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   33:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   34:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   35:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   36:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   37:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   40:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
        line   41:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   42:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   43:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   44:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   45:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   46:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   47:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   48:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   49:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   55:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
        line   56:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   57:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   58:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   59:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   60:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   61:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   62:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   72:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   73:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   74:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   75:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   76:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   77:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   78:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   79:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   87:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
        line   88:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   89:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   90:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   91:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   92:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   93:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   94:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   95:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  103:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  104:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  105:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  106:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  107:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  108:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  109:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  110:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  113:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function airline#parts#define
        line  114:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  115:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  116:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  122:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function airline#parts#define
        line  123:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  124:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  125:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  128:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function airline#parts#define
        line  129:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  130:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  131:
        E15: Invalid expression: 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function airline#parts#define
        line  132:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  133:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  135:
        E697: Missing end of List ']': 
        E116: Invalid arguments for function airline#parts#define_empty
        line  136:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  137:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  138:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        --- Auto-Commands ---
        Error detected while processing function <SNR>46_airline_toggle:
        line   19:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   20:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        --- Auto-Commands ---
        line   33:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        --- Auto-Commands ---
        VimEnter
        *NERDTree /home/qiuxiao/
        FileExplorer  VimEnter
        *sil call s:VimEnter(expand("<amatch>"))
        youcompletemeStart  VimEnter
        *call youcompleteme#Enable()
        NERDTreeHijackNetrw  VimEnter
        *silent! autocmd! FileExplorer
        call nerdtree#checkForBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
        matchparen  WinEnter
        *call s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
        CtrlPMRUF  BufWinEnter
        *cal s:record(expand('<abuf>', 1))
        filetypeplugin  FileType
        *call s:LoadFTPlugin()
        filetypeindent  FileType
        *call s:LoadIndent()
        syntaxset  FileType
        *exe "set syntax=" . expand("<amatch>")
        line   35:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        --- Auto-Commands ---
        line   43:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line   44:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        --- Auto-Commands ---
        Error detected while processing 

    /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim:
        line  151:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  152:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  153:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  154:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  155:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        line  156:
        E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: I think it was this update that broke plugins for me on Linux Mint 18.3 -- vim-gtk3 (2:8.1.0037-0york1~16.04) to 2:8.1.0037+v8.1.0053-0~ubuntu16.04.1 -- from jonathonf/vim PPA

Comment: @MikeLippert I am on ElementaryOS and the update only included `vim`, `vim-tiny`, `vim-runtime`. it looks like to me, it is vim itself breaking it.

Comment: I agree. Look at your cpoptions, I found a thread https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_use/94wo-ZiqJwo/discussion which seemed relevant and posted a msg to it.

Comment: @MikeLippert thanks Mike. I also raised an issue on `vim`'s github. we can keep an eye on there as well.

Comment: I have a similar issue, when I launch VIM I get an error

Error detected while processing function pathogen#infect[8]..pathogen#interpose[12]..pathogen#is_disabled:
line    5:
E15: Invalid expression: 
E15: Invalid expression: 
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Fixed by version `2:8.1.0061-0york1~16.04`

---

It seems the updated version `2:8.1.0037+v8.1.0053-0~ubuntu16.04.1` packages from jonathonf's vim PPA have an issue. In particular it seems to be `vim-tiny` and `vim-common` which are now putting some files in `/usr/share/vim/vim810037+v81/` instead of `/usr/share/vim/vim81/`

I was able to fix the problem (**a stopgap measure** and I'm **not sure how it will work once the packages are fixed**) by:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/vim/vim810037+v81/debian.vim /usr/share/vim/vim81/
```

then edit and change the runtimepath

```
sudo vim /usr/share/vim/vim81/debian.vim
:%s/vim810037+v81/vim81/
:wq
```

---

For more information about the cause see jonathonf's comments in https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3014

Comment: thanks for the time you spent on this Mike and it seems to be a decent enough fix. now we know what's going on I think Jonathan will look into it soon. Don't forget we could also just build the latest vim from source (cheating here :P), if anyone bumps into this again.

Comment: It's been fixed now by Jonathon F., the owner of the PPA.

Answer (score 1):

If you met error liking this:

```
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname

/start/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim:
```

just try use this below to fix:

```
cd && cd /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/ctrlp.vim/plugin/

git pull --rebase
```

Also, to fix the below:

```
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname

/start/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim:
```

just use:

```
cd /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/tagbar/plugin/

git pull --rebase
```

And, to fix the below liking:

```
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname

/start/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim:
```

just use:

```
cd /home/myname/.vim/pack/myname/start/vim-fugitive/plugin/ && git pull --rebase
```

END!